# unity c# set text true with GetMouseButtondown

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, text

I basicly just want to talk to an NPC. The text should show up once I pressed `MouseButton(0)`. With my current code the text stays as long as I hold the mouse button down.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Input.GetMouseButton(0) && cc.height < 20 && Vector3.Distance(Larry.transform.position, this.transform.position) < 10)
{
    text1.SetActive(true);
```

So how should this if statement look like if i want to see the text until `Vector3.Distance(Larry.transform.position, this.transform.position) < 10` is not true anymore?

Comment: `Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Input.GetMouseButton(0)`? You have that condition twice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that code block is placed in e.g. `Update` where it is called every frame you simply have to leave the text enabled until you match the opposite condition

It also is enough to use [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) (fires only once at the beginning when mouse button is pressed) instead of `Input.GetMouseButton` (fires repeatedly every frame while mouse button stays pressed) to use only one call for enabling the text since it will stay enabled "automatically".

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && cc.height < 20 && Vector3.Distance(Larry.transform.position, transform.position) < 10)
{
    // Enable the text
    text1.SetActive(true);
}
// Meanwhile the second condiction isn't matched 
// the text stays active anyway
// Use if else to avoid an unnecessary check
// since only one of the two conditions can be true at the same time
else if(Vector3.Distance(Larry.transform.position, transform.position) >= 10)
{
    // Disable the text
    text1.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do the same but with the oposite of the `Vector3.Distance<10` like this:

```
 if(Vector3.Distance(Larry.transform.position, this.transform.position) => 10)
     text1.SetActive(false);
```

Oh, and you have a redundant `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`, I believe only calling it once should be enough.

Comment: `>=` (logical comparison operator) not `=>` (lambda operator).